# Why is a string not being returned form this nested if statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working in react, and this function outputs a string to a className. right now no string is being returned. I can throw in an alert, and it fires, but within the map statement, no 'green' or 'block' strings are coming back.

```
boardHiglighter(id){
        let submittedWords = this.state.submittedWords
        if(this.state.currentBoardValue.includes(id)){
            return 'red'
        }
        if(this.state.wordSubmitted){
            submittedWords.map(elem=>{              
                if(elem.word.wordLocation.includes(id)){
                    console.log('map if')
                    return 'green'
                }
                else{
                    console.log('map else')
                    return 'block'
                }
            })            
        }
        else{
            return 'block'
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you must return also map()'s result

```
    if(this.state.wordSubmitted){
        return submittedWords.map(elem=>{              
            if(elem.word.wordLocation.includes(id)){
                console.log('map if')
                return 'green'
            }
            else{
                console.log('map else')
                return 'block'
            }
        })            
    }
```

** Array.map() returns Array. So if you want return just a word not array, pick one of map()'s result or use Array.reduce()

Answer (score 1):

The `return`s inside the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) only returns the value that's going to be pushed to the new array. `submittedWords.map` would return a new array (not a string) with string values that are either `green` or `block`.